# A derivative which is not Lebesgue integrable on any interval?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-integral

If $f=x^2\sin(x^{-2})$, then $f'$ exists everywhere (including $x=0$) but $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ (precisely because of the singularity at $x=0).$ I'm trying to find a function $f$ such that $f'$ exists everywhere but $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable on any interval. Perhaps someone can recall a standard example?

Comment: Something like taking an enumeration $(q_i)$ of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ then setting $$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-i} f(x - q_i)$$ may work, but I'm not sure whether it's differentiable or not  (the usual method using local uniform convergence of partial sums of derivatives clearly won't work; and I don't think it would for anything unbounded, which is neccasary!).

Comment: @Aubrey, I am sorry, why $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable? Thank you. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_0%5E1+%28+2+x+sin%281%2Fx%5E2%29+-+%282+cos%281%2Fx%5E2%29%29%2Fx%29

Comment: @Quiet_waters That's to do with the definition of [Lebesgue integrability for signed functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Signed_functions). In this case, $ \int _ { [ 0 , 1 ] } | f ' | \ \mathrm d \mu = + \infty $, hence non-integrability of $ f ' $.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no such functions. Since $f$ is continuous, the derivative 
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))
$$
is a pointwise limit of continuous functions, i.e., a function of [Baire class $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1). Functions of Baire class $1$ have [many points of continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381546/). Every point of continuity has a neighborhood in which the function is bounded; since it's also a Borel function, it is Lebesgue integrable in such neighborhood.