# Seeking an example of continuous function that has no integrable derivative

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I am seeking for a function $[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous and has derivative almost everywhere, but this derivative is not integrable niether on sense of improper integrals.

For instance, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is s.t. $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable. I am seeking an example s.t. $f'(x)$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

**This is the difference on the question [What is an example that a function is differentiable but derivative is not Riemann integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/what-is-an-example-that-a-function-is-differentiable-but-derivative-is-not-riema)**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941842/447237 check if this helps

Comment: @Aierel thank you so much. I feel that I have a problem of language here, maybe you could help me. The example of Aubrey in that link you've posted has a finite improper integral https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_0%5E1+%28+2+x+sin%281%2Fx%5E2%29+-+%282+cos%281%2Fx%5E2%29%29%2Fx%29. I've thinked that this means that $f'(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable, but Aubrey said its not... How can I name the functions that have finite improper integrals...?

Comment: So, I am seeking for functions s.t. derivative is s.t. $1/x$, I mean, the integral diverges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f$ to be $0$ on the Cantor set $E$, and on each open interval $(a_k,b_k)$ of $[0,1] \backslash E$ take $f(x) = (b_k-a_k)^c (x-a_k)(b_k-x)$ where $-2 < c < -2 + \log_3(2)$.  This is differentiable everywhere except on $E$.  The condition $c > -2$ ensures that $f$ is continuous, while $c < -2 + \log_3(2)$ ensures that the derivative is not Lebesgue integrable.